# Proof of a closed point set

Tags: real-analysis

I have this theorem: If f is a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [a,b] and there is a point x in [a,b] so that f(x) is greater than or equal to zero, then the set of all numbers x is an element of [a,b] such that f(x) > or equal to 0 is a closed point set.

I already know that the system f(p1),f(p2),f(px) converges to f(x) according to this theorem( If f is a function and x1,x2,x3,... is a sequence of points in the domain of f converging to the number x in the domain of f, and f is a continuous function at (x,f(x)), then f(x1),f(x2),... converges to f(x). So since every point in the sequence f(r1),f(r2),f(r3),... is equal to f(p), then f(r) = f(p). So the limit point at y is in M.
Since every function of M is in M, then M is a closed point set.

Now I need to apply this to this proof..
If f is a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [a,b] and there is a point x in [a,b] so that f(x) = -3, then the set of all real numbers x in [a,b] such that f(x) < or equal to -2 is a closed point set.

Comment: Do you know the definition (or equivalence) of continuity using open/closed sets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed Point Set and Continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540593/closed-point-set-and-continuity)

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecesary requirements for $f$. I will prove the following stronger statement: if $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, the set

$$
g^{-1}(-\infty, l] = \{x \in Dom(g) : g(x) \leq l\}
$$

is closed for each $l \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, you can observe that if $g \equiv f \rvert_{[a,b]}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $[a,b]$, then your set is just $g^{-1}(-\infty,-2]$ which is closed. So,

*Proof*. Let $l \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq g^{-1}(-\infty, l]$ is a  sequence that converges to certain $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It suffices to show that $x \in g^{-1}(-\infty, l]$, and this is because since $g(x_n) \leq l$ for each $n$ by hypothesis,
$$
g(x) = g(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n) \leq l
$$

where the second equality is due to the continuity of $g$. This completes the proof.